# Executar Consulta SQL multiplas vezes entre duas datas (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, query, for, while

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para executar uma consulta SQL entre duas datas onde por exemplo:

o usuário vai escolher duas datas:

data_inicial = 20/04/2020
data_final = 25/04/2020

então eu queria saber como faço para fazer isso (por exemplo):

```
select * from teste where data = 20/04/2020 ... ( data inicial)
select * from teste where data = 21/04/2020 ... 
select * from teste where data = 22/04/2020 ...
select * from teste where data = 23/04/2020 ...  
select * from teste where data = 24/04/2020 ...  
select * from teste where data = 25/04/2020 ... ( data final )`
```

Tentei isso no php mas nao com esta SQL, botei uma de exemplo :

```
 $data_ini = "24/04/2020";
 $data_fim = "05/05/2020";

 $dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data_ini);
 $dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data_fim);

 $data_inicio = new DateTime(($dt1->format('Y-m-d')));
 $data_fim = new DateTime(($dt2->format('Y-m-d')));

 // Resgata diferença entre as datas
 $dateInterval = $data_inicio->diff($data_fim);

 $i = 0;

 for($i = 0; $i <= $dateInterval->days; $i++) {

 $dataSql = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$i.'days', strtotime(($dt1->format('Y-m-d')))));
         //echo $dataSql;
         echo "<br/>";

         $sql = "select * from teste where data = $dataSql";

         echo $i.' '.$sql;
         echo '<br>';
         echo '<br>';
  }
```

Resultado mostrado no echo:

```
0 select * from teste where data = 2020-04-24


1 select * from teste where data = 2020-04-25


2 select * from teste where data = 2020-04-26


3 select * from teste where data = 2020-04-27


4 select * from teste where data = 2020-04-28


5 select * from teste where data = 2020-04-29


6 select * from teste where data = 2020-04-30


7 select * from teste where data = 2020-05-01
```

Fim

Desculpe se isso não for possivel, sou estudante e essa e minha primeira pergunta, essa solução pode ser tanto no proprio mysql ou no php, se alguem pudesse me ajudar... Muito obrigado

Comment: Você precisa efetivamente fazer diferentes SELECTs ou bastaria apenas um SELECT verificando se a data está dentro do intervalo? `... WHERE data BETWEEN '2020-04-20' AND '2020-04-25' ...`.

Comment: Ola eu gostaria de fazer diferentes selects repetidamente entre as datas que o usuario escolheu isso é possivel? E a data de cada consulta é a data inicial +1 dia e assim por diante ate chegar na data final

Comment: Se você quer algo procedimental então crie uma rotina procedimental. O SQL é uma linguagem declarativa. Pesquise por procedure no manual.

Comment: No seu código, ele imprime na tela, os X selects o que você quer é rodar no banco? função mysqli_query() por exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Tem duas foras de fazer:

> Entre datas com BETWEEN

```
select 
  * 
from teste 
where data between '20/04/2020' and '24/04/2020'
```

Isso ira retornar os dia (20, 21, 22, 23 e 24) caso existam

> Uma ou outra data

```
select 
  * 
from teste 
where data = '20/04/2020' 
or data = '24/04/2020'
```

Isso irá retornar somente o dia 20 e 24 caso existam

Todo o resultado será retprmado em uma só tabela.